# Word for crying after anger

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am looking for a word which defines the people who start crying after an outburst. I was thinking of sentimental but it seems like a wrong choice.

Comment: In what sense? *Emotional*? *Drained*? *Cathartic*? How will the word be used? Provide an example sentence with a blank spot into which it would be inserted.

Comment: I'm thinking "tantrum".

Comment: To cry tears of relief.

Answer (score 0):

'Consternation' comes to mind. It's a sort of surprise or paroxysm that comes from something capricious.

Comment: ...a real citation from a reputable source would be helpful, like [consternation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consternation)...but this does not actually address the issue of "crying" as asked in the  the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Relieved. The intensity of an outburst, is similar to the relief experienced after orgasm when, in some people the post-orgasmic relief valve is opened to enable expression of raw emotion. A time of vulnerability. The deeply emotive expression of one's inner self (not dissimilar from unresolved issues expressed in dream). 
I realize this is not a single-word answer but it may move us closer.

Comment: Perhaps you mean release in your sex example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single word for it but I have heard the phenomenon called "angry tears". It comes from a combined feeling of hurt and frustration. Children do it best and frequently, though adults are not immune. Tears are humans' way of letting another know that they have been hurt and want/need support (or you to change your mind about that treat). The anger comes from the frustration of you not behaving like they expect.